# .NET 5 - NHibernate: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services, .net-5

I'm working on an API, which i recently moved from **.NET Framework 4.6.1** to **.NET Core 5**.

The API is using **NHibernate** (5.3.10) with unit of work pattern and async / await methods on an AWS **RDS Aurora** (1.23.0) MySQL 5.6 version.

As on .NET Framework all seems fine, after the migration to .NET 5, we started seeing **random** db connection timeouts:

```
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnectionAsync(String connectionString, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.<>c__DisplayClass81_0.<<GetConnectionAsync>g__InternalGetConnectionAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.PrepareAsync(DbCommand cmd, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReaderAsync(DbCommand cmd, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSetAsync(DbCommand st, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAsync(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer, QueryCacheResultBuilder queryCacheResultBuilder, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollectionsAsync(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer, QueryCacheResultBuilder queryCacheResultBuilder, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoListAsync(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer, QueryCacheResultBuilder queryCacheResultBuilder, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

ConnectionString:
`Server=rds-cluster;Port=3306;Database=test;Uid=a;Pwd=b;CharSet=utf8;Convert Zero Datetime=true;default command timeout=90;Connection Timeout=5;SSL MODE=None;`

Even if i set the connection timeout to 30 seconds, it will still fail. As the connections normally are opened really fast (few ms).

I tried to work it out with a connection pool approach:
`Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=500;Min Pool Size=100;`
but doesn't seem to solve the problem. Also tested with AWS RDS Proxy.
To mention that this occurs even with a few connections, not just high traffic.

I tried to reproduce this with a simpler application, which works like this:

1. Create an nhibernate factory at app startup

```
 System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var configuration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
            configuration.DataBaseIntegration(c =>
                                              {
                                                  c.Dialect<MySQL55InnoDBDialect>();
                                                  c.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                                              });

            var factory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

2. Having a DataContext class:

```
    {
        private readonly ISession nHibernateSession;

        public DataContext(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
        {
            nHibernateSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (nHibernateSession != null && nHibernateSession.IsOpen)
            {

                nHibernateSession.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public ISession GetSession()
        {
            return nHibernateSession;
        }
    }

  public class DataContextFactory : IDataContextFactory
    {
        private readonly ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public DataContextFactory(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
        {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        public IDataContext GetDataContext()
        {
            return new DataContext(sessionFactory);
        }

    }
```

3. Running method

```
        {
            NHibernate.ISessionFactory sessionFactory = MySqlInitializer.GetSessionFactory(connectionString);
            DataContextFactory dataContextFactory = new DataContextFactory(sessionFactory);

            ParallelLoopResult parallelLoopResult = Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, range), parallelOptions: new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = parallel }, async (i) =>
            {
                    try
                    {
                        using (var dataContext = dataContextFactory.GetDataContext())
                        {
                            var session = dataContext.GetSession();
                            await session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM test.users limit " + i).ListAsync();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        writeLog("Error: " + ex);
                    }

            });

            while (!parallelLoopResult.IsCompleted)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
          
        }
```

Testing with like 30 con/s, 80-90% from them are passing, but the rest are giving the above error.
The query should be fast and in the first seconds, most of the connections are done in like 100-200 ms, but after a while it starts to fail.
My approach was to lower the connection timeout and increase the retries on the whole using, it helps a little, but a few still fails even after 5 retries
On the API this issue is more visible, as there are different types of queries running there.

I tried to change the nhibernate versions or move to .NET 3, but the result is the same.
The nhibernate pattern is basically the same between the .NET Framework (where i can't reproduce this) and .NET 5

I also tried to reproduce it on a local mysql 5.6 server and i could reproduce the issue, but after setting the connection pool, seems to do the trick, at least on local, but not on the AWS RDS instance. Also tried on AWS RDS aurora mysql 5.7 and 5.8, still happens.

Had raised a ticket with the AWS RDS team and they says it's a client issue and the infrastructure looks right.

Can't find any related tickets or most of them are just saying: increase timeout duration or increase command duration (which is not right in this case), and like i said, this happens randomly, most likely because async / await open new connections.

Any suggestions what should i try out next?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with .NET 5. On the other hand, that can't be said about the MySQL drivers in general with their faked async methods and glacial support. Let's face it, Oracle has no reason to make working with .NET Core easy, quite the opposite. They've actually answered they don't care about providing true async methods in issues. The problem you get is a Connector/NET error, not an NHibernate or .NET error.  I've run into problems with Connector/NET within minutes while trying to connect to a database.

Comment: I'd **strongly** advise switching to the third-party, actively maintained and supported [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) package. MySqlConnector is almost as popular as Oracle's driver (28M vs 32M downloads) and [its default behavior](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/) solves several problems in MySqlConnector/NET. For example, Oracle's driver doesn't reset connections when connection pooling is used, while MySqlConnector does.

Comment: The [Migrating from Connector/NET](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/) lists ~100 bugs that are solved in MySqlConnector even though they remain in Connector/Net . Some of them affect the connection pool and the creation or reuse of pooled connections.

Comment: Connector/NET's fake async methods may be behind the current problem as well. Back in .NET Framework 4.6.1 async operations weren't so widespread but in .NET Core, async is at the very heart of the runtime and BCL. Libraries like NHibernate use async operations a *lot* more when they're available. An `await` that ends up blocking the calling thread may not have been such an issue 8 years ago, but today it could easily lead to deadlocks.

Comment: The problem is shown in the question's call stack `NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnectionAsync` ends up calling `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()` and blocking. If `GetConnectionAsync` or its callers expected to be able to do some other work concurrently, they'll fail because `GetConnectionAsync` blocked when it shouldn't

Comment: Cheers for the detailed answer :) I'm trying out this nhibernate extension: https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.MySqlConnector which is using MySqlConnector. I will let you know the result